# DB mail stopped working on Clustered instance

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Database mail stopped working after enabling 'Hide instance' and 'Disable remote connection' on SQL 2008 R2 two node clustered instance however DB mail is working fine on SQL 2016 two node clustered instance after applying same SQL hardening.

I am not really sure if SQL hardening is causing this issue

I found following error in event log:

> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException
>   Message: There was an error on the connection. Reason: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: What happens if you "unhide" the instance? Does it start working again?

Comment: Disabling "Hide instance" worked however it is working fine for SQL 2016 with same option enabled so not sure why it's affecting only 2008R2 and 2012 version.  I did created Alias and did some test but it didn't work out for me so finally I'll go with disable "Hide instance" option. Thanks

Comment: Are your lower versions running on named instances, and your 2016 on a default instance? After all this "hiding" as it were, just disables the browser service (by the way this is just security theatre, it does not provide you any higher level of security with SQL Server as a simple port scan will show SQL Server listening)

Comment: ... is the 2008R2 instance a named instance and the 2016 one a default instance?

Comment: 2008R2 instance and 2016 instance both run on different cluster. I found following link which I also used to troubleshoot an issue without disabling "hide instance" and it worked.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326746(v=sql.105).aspx